# Routing issue with - in variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have a route in my asp.net mvc 2 site that looks like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "media_display",
                "Media/{mediaId}-{mediaName}",
                new { controller = "Media", action = "Display" },
                new { mediaId = @"\d+" }
            );
```

Where mediaId is the id, and mediaName is the title of the media.
An example

> www.example.com/Media/1-test-media-list

Where the id is 1, and the name is "test media list", the problem here is that i replace space " " with -, and that ruins my route.

I just can't figure out how to make this so "mediaName" can contain a -.

i also have the following rute, but the solution should be the same.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "media_display",
                "Media/{mediaId}-{mediaName}/edit",
                new { controller = "Media", action = "Edit" },
                new { mediaId = @"\d+" }
            );
```

Also are it possible to make a route that will catch all the following 3 exampels, right now do i just have 3 different routes, but i would like to cut this down.

> www.example.com/Media/1-test-media-list
>
> www.example.com/Media/1-
>
> www.example.com/Media/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider a more elegant and simpler solution to have `www.example.com/Media/1/test-media-list`.

If you insist on your url examples, make a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "media_display",
                "Media/{slug}",
                new { controller = "Media", action = "Display" },
            );
```

and use technique described in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx) to parse the id, name or whatever you need from the slug into you action parameters.

Comment: I would say that www.example.com/Media/1-test-media-list is the most elegant :D
The slug sulotion, will break the making of urls where i use Html.Action("Display", "Media", new { mediaId = 1, mediaName = "Some Name" } );

But if no one are able to help me with the {mediaId}-{mediaName} sulotion will i use {mediaId}/{mediaName}

Comment: I used to have a property that returned generated slug in my view model when I used that. Then you would have Html.Action("Display", "Media", new { slug = Model.MediaSlug } ). But I still think /id/name is nicer. Look! Even SO uses it ;)

Comment: I have used the /id/name solution

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with a regex route i found at http://iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

```
routes.Add(
    new RegexRoute(@"^Media\/(?<mediaId>\d+)-(?<mediaName>[^\/]*)$", 
        new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
        controller = "Media", action = "Display", playlistName = "" })
    }
```